# Postgresql ColdFusion CFQuery Block

Tags: postgresql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, postgresql-9.1

I am new to ColdFusion, I have written a block of Postgres code in CFQuery :

```
<cffunction name="insertToReport" access="private" returntype="struct" output="false" >

  <cfset var xyz = structNew() >
  <cfset xyz.code = "">
      <cfquery name="querysampleresult" datasource="abc">
            DO            
            $BODY$
                DECLARE resultValue int;
            BEGIN
               resultValue = 1;
               SELECT resultValue INTO resultValue ;    
            END;
            $BODY$
      </cfquery>

            <cfset xyz.code = querysampleresult.resultValue  >

           <cfreturn xyz >
</cffunction>
```

My problem is that I am unable to access the variable `resultValue` outside of the CFQuery tag, i.e it is throwing the exception:

```
Element RESULTVALUE is undefined in querysampleresult
```

This is occurring at the CFSet statement at the end of function here:

```
<cfset xyz.code = querysampleresult.resultValue  >
```

I don't know how I can set the variable `resultValue` in the structure and I am bound to return a structure from here to the calling environment.
Please help me in this, Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An anonymous code block (`DO`) always returns `void`. You need to use a function to return anything else:

```
create function f()
returns integer as $body$
declare 
    resultValue integer;
begin
    resultValue := 1;
    return resultValue;
end;
$body$
language plpgsql
```

After the function is created you can use it in your query:

```
select f() as resultValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add another select statement into the query that selects the result value.  Right now you're selecting INTO a table, which doesn't return a query.

```
<cffunction name="insertToReport" access="private" returntype="struct" output="false" >
<cfargument name="rptDataObj" required="yes" type="com.certain.register123.data.reportData" hint="The affected report.">
<cfargument name="maxColumns" type="numeric" required="false" default="10" hint="The maximum number of active columns that should be saved to the report. " ><!--- As of REG-559 20060215, the default was 10 --->
<cfargument name="dsn" type="string" required="false" default="#application.portals.data[request.applicationName].dsn#" >
<cfset var uiCustomColumn = queryNew("") >
<cfset var strSaveError = structNew() >
<cfset strSaveError.code = 0 >
<cfset strSaveError.message = "">
<cfset strSaveError.udcId = "">


<cfquery name="uiCustomColumn" datasource="#arguments.dsn#">
DO            
$BODY$
    DECLARE resultValue int;
    DECLARE nextId bigint;
    DECLARE maxColumns bigint;
    DECLARE udcReportId bigint; /*Have to use this value more than once, so declare it to reduce number of parameters*/
    DECLARE udcOrder int;  /*Have to use this value more than once, so declare it to reduce number of parameters*/

BEGIN
    udcReportId = #arguments.rptDataObj.getId()# ;
    maxColumns = #arguments.maxColumns# ;

    IF (( select count( udc_id ) from user_defined_column WHERE udc_frn_rpt_id = udcReportId AND udc_is_active = true ) >= maxColumns) THEN
        BEGIN
            resultValue = 1; /*There isn't an available slot for this column */
        END;
        ELSE
        BEGIN

            nextId = (SELECT coalesce( MAX(udc_id), 0 ) FROM user_defined_column ) + 1 ;
            udcOrder = (SELECT coalesce( MAX(udc_order), 0 ) FROM user_defined_column WHERE udc_frn_rpt_id = udcReportId AND udc_is_active = true ) + 1 ;

            INSERT INTO user_defined_column(
                udc_id
                ,udc_frn_rpt_id
                ,udc_label
                ,udc_data
                ,udc_type
                ,udc_order
                ,udc_is_active
                ,udc_date_created
                ,udc_date_modified
            )
            VALUES(
                nextId
                ,udcReportId
                ,'hi'
                ,'hi'
                ,12
                ,udcOrder
                ,true
                ,now()
                ,now()
            );


            resultValue = 0;
        END ;
    END IF;
    SELECT resultValue, nextId INTO resultValue  /*Set a success result */
          , nextId;

    SELECT resultValue;

END;
$BODY$
</cfquery>

<cfset strSaveError.code = uiCustomColumn.resultValue  >
<cfset strSaveError.udcId = uiCustomColumn.nextId  >

<cfreturn strSaveError >
```

Comment: If I am using "SELECT resultValue" then exception is thrown as : ERROR: query has no destination for result data :(

Comment: we can't use select statement directly in pl/pgsql , we have to either return any value or have to put resultValue in some variable with INTO  clause.So, your above code seems not working in making resultValue to be available to uiCustomColumn ousite the cfquery block. But thanks for your support. (

Comment: @Satish Yes you can use a select in plpgsql. The problem is that if you do it in an anonymous code block in instead of in a function you either use `into` as you say or you do a `perform 'select resultValue'`. Neither will work because `void` will always be returned.

Comment: @Clodoaldo yes you are right , I have changed the anonymous block  with a function in order to access the parameters outside the cfQuery, Thanks for all your support.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that.  It's been a while since I've worked with PGSQL so I was going on memory.  Oh well!